# What does "the look of" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following phrase has been taken from Wikipedia's [computer science style guides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Computer_science/Manual_of_style#Code_samples):

> Samples of actual source get included in articles for a variety of reasons, although the most typical reasons are to demonstrate the "look" of a particular language, to provide examples of language-specific constructs or features, and to provide examples of algorithms not easily expressed in pseudocode.

What is the meaning of the 'to demonstrate the "look" of a particular language'?

I have two variants:

1. to demonstrate particular language's point of view, approach, which is more at the logical level, than just visual representation
2. to demonstrate how something (visually) looks like when written in a particular language. In this case "look" reminds of "[look and feel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_and_feel)"

Or maybe neither variant is good.

Comment: I think you would be better off using wikipedia's talk page for the article to discuss this with the author as we would only be guessing.

Comment: Do you want to say that the expression is ambiguous? I thought "the look of" is idiomatic.

Comment: Definitely **2** but not quite what is meant by "look and feel." Various languages follow various structures of coding, a "style" which is both idiosyncratic and characteristic of the language. You get the drift.

Comment: I think it's similar to _style_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"look" of a particular programming language refers to snapshot of the structure, basic constructs and syntax.  Usually "hello world" program is used for every language to illustrate the same.

Comment: So, is it more number 2 then?

Comment: No, not just visual.  It is more like 'a simple program in this language would use constructs as in this program'.